# React native Admob Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException:

Tags: android, react-native, admob

Before, my app work fine. Today I rebuild and it show error `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException:`
I search and find solution is add my admob id in `AndroidManifest.xml` and I add it and rebuild, but it show same error.
[image]

How I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line in your project AndroidManifest.xml, inside 'application' tag

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="[appid here]"/>
```